# What about dimension of $W_1 \cap W_2 $?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be vector space of dimension 6 over  field $Z/7Z$. Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be two subspaces of $V$. Let $\dim(W_1)=4$, $\dim(W_2)=3$. what about dimension of $W_1 \cap W_2 $?
I know the formula $\dim(W_1 + W_2) = \dim(W_1) + \dim(W_2) - \dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$. I tried with this formula but could not find the proper answer.
I am confused with, is dimension ($W_1 \cap W_2$) one? or greater than equal to one or anything else?

Comment: Of course, the dimension can be as big as 3, if $W_2\subset W_1$. It can't be bigger; it can be as small as 1, but no smaller; and it can be anything in between, that is, it can be 2.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson what is the use of field Z/6Z here?

Comment: Is $W_1 \bigcup W_2 = V $ true?

Comment: Z / 6 Z isn't a field, nor does it appear in the question, Arun, and the union of two subspaces is never a vector space, unless one of the subspaces contains the other.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $W_1 \subseteq W_1 + W_2 \subseteq V$. So $4 = \dim(W_1) \leq \dim(W_1 + W_2) \leq \dim(V) = 6$. Putting in the information we know into your formula gives that:

$$\dim(W_1 + W_2) = 7 - \dim(W_1 \cap W_2).$$

Using our inequality with this gives:

$$4 \leq 7 - \dim(W_1\cap W_2) \leq 6.$$

This inequality simplifies to:

$$ 1 \leq \dim(W_1 \cap W_2) \leq 3.$$

Without more information, we can't say more.

Comment: can we say $(W_1 \bigcup W_2)= V$ by the above information?

Comment: $W_1 \cup W_2$ is not a subspace unless either $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ or $W_2 \subseteq W_1$.

Comment: So in fact, $W_1 \cup W_2$ cannot be $V$.

Comment: Yes true...Thank you